# re.split need separate by a specific symbol at the beginning and end

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to obtain a regular expression that gives me the data set by commas, but these groups have to be in a shape, as shown:

input

```
"avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host},avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host},top(avg:system.load.1{*},5,'mean','desc'),top(avg:system.load.1{*}, 5, 'mean', 'desc')"
```

output

```
["avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}",
"avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}",
"top(avg:system.load.1{*}, 5, 'mean', 'desc')",
"top(avg:system.load.1{*}, 5, 'mean', 'desc')"]
```

i actually use:

```
re.split('([^()]*},|[^()]*\),)',input)
```

but i get:

```
['', 'avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host},avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host},', 'top(', 'avg:system.load.1{*},', '', "5,'mean','desc'),", 'top(', 'avg:system.load.1{*},', " 5, 'mean', 'desc')"]
```

Comment: avoid using `input` as a variable name, it is a reserved word in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a different pattern, that looks for commas with a negative lookahead for digits, quotes, or spaces.

```
re.split(r",(?![\s\d'])", input)
```

Testing

```
import re
inp = "avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host},avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host},top(avg:system.load.1{*},5,'mean','desc'),top(avg:system.load.1{*}, 5, 'mean', 'desc')"
print(*re.split(r",(?![\s\d'])", inp), sep='\n')
```

Output

```
avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}
avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}*avg:system.cpu.user{*} by {host}
top(avg:system.load.1{*},5,'mean','desc')
top(avg:system.load.1{*}, 5, 'mean', 'desc')
```

Comment: +1 Very nice answer, this solves my problem, I was trying with specific symbols.
now I understand that with patterns I can do it...
I need to investigate more about how it works.
thanks you

Comment: @DavidMedina try [regexr.com](https://www.regexr.com)

Comment: i was trying, now i know how this works, good page, i will use this to test next regex, thanks you again